# How do I export a .dae so that textures are included when I import it?

Tags: texturing, export

I've recently used Blender to work on a model, and I need to export it as a dae file, but after I export it, I find that the textures don't import with the model, for some reason.

Just so you know, yes, I have these options checked.

[image]

But, no matter what program I try to import the model into, the textures do not import.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 1):

Check the texture coordinates for your object(s) and make sure they're using "UV" and not some other coordinate system (e.g. "generated," "object," etc). (Also: If you haven't already UV unwrapped and mapped your object(s), you'll need to.)  :)

Comment: I tried those things, but it still didn't work.